# Java code to draw ellipse around face

Tags: java, opencv

I found a code to draw rectangle around detected face in an image. I need help to draw ellipse instead of rectangle. I f I use draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y,                           rectwidth, rectheight)); function then I am not able to figure out the x,y. 
I found the code on this link: https://blog.openshift.com/day-12-opencv-face-detection-for-java-developers/

Comment: Please show some code.. and some effort. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

x and y correspond to the top-left vertex of the rectangle. Given that the function you've specified takes only 4 parameters, I'm guessing it is an upright ellipse that you're drawing.

If you've found the code to draw rectangles around faces, then you should be able to extract (x,y) from there itself